# Exception handling for Email command

Tags: linux, shell, mailx

How to handle the exception when mailx command gets failed,

following is the kick start for handling but not working,

Negative scenrios for handling the mailx command:

When email id is invalid format, like ganeshfriends@gmail.com 
When no email body

```
$rst = `/usr/bin/echo \"test123456\" | /usr/bin/mailx -s \'test subject\' ganeshfriends\@gmail.com 2>/dev/null; >> ~/151534/email_err.cfg`;
```

Comment: `2>/dev/null` discards error message from `mailx`.

Comment: What language are you using?  `$rst = \` ...` is not a unix shell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to handle `mailx` process exit code and if it is non-zero parse its standard error output stream (which your command line redirects to `/dev/null`).

Another way is to use, for example, [Python's smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html). It reports errors as exceptions, like `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused`, `smtplib.SMTPDataError`, etc.., which makes it easier to tell one kind error from another.

Answer (score 0):

> Negative scenrios for handling the mailx command:
>   - When email id is invalid format, like ganeshfriends@gmail.com
>   - When no email body

There is nothing wrong with that email address you give as an example.

- If, by "invalid", you mean the email address does not exist, you cannot test that beforehand: you have to send an email to it and see if you receive a bounce back from the recipient's mail server -- clearly this is hard to automate.
- If you want to check the format of the email address, even that is tricky (see, for example, [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)). At a minimum, you can check that the address contains a <kbd>@</kbd> and a <kbd>.</kbd> and some text around those characters. In bash you could write

  `if [[ "$addr" == ?*@?*.?* ]]; then echo OK; else echo BAD; fi`

To test the body, you have to capture the output of the program and check if it's empty:

```
body=$( /some/program ...)
if [ -z "$body" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: email body is empty!"
  exit
fi

echo "$body" | /usr/bin/mailx -s "subject" recipient@example.com
```